# ext js get Modified records with model validations error

Tags: extjs, datastore

I want to get modified, new or deleted recors from ext js data store, the problem its that records with model validations errors are not returned in getModifiedRecord or getRemovedRecords methods from dataStore no matter that the records is mark as phantom. there is any method that return this records?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own state. For example, if you created, edited, deleted a record, you can set a new record property.

```
myRecord.set('modified', true);
```

You can now get all the records and check for that property.

```
store.getRange();
```

You can add separate states if you want to.

```
myRecord.set('state', 'new');
myRecord.set('state', 'modified');
```

For the deleted records, you may want to push it to an array because you cannot get it inside the store (I guess).

```
var deletedRecords = [];

deletedRecords.push(myRecord);
```

Hope it helps.